# How to hide events in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, outlook

The company I work for likes for us to use Outlook to schedule everything. If we aren't going to be at work at a specific time, they ask us to create an event spanning that time, and mark it as "Out Of Office". That way, if anyone attempts to schedule a meeting with you, or checks your schedule, it will inform them that you won't be there.

I am working part-time to fit a schedule around my school schedule; as a result, I have a lot of blocked off events on my calendar. Basically, all the times I'm in class are blocked off. I am syncing my Outlook and Google Calendar to my Android phone.

Now, all of those blocked off time slots are rather annoying to me because it causes everything else during those times to be scrunched up. It's hard to just look at my calendar on my phone and tell what is going on next. Basically, I want the "Out Of Office" events removed from my Android's Calendar display, without removing them from Outlook.

So far, I have tried to delete the event from my phone, but that syncs with Outlook, and causes it to be deleted from my Outlook account. I then tried to create a new calendar in Outlook called "Out Of Office" and add all of the events to that, then hide that on my phone. However, when I do that, it won't block people from scheduling meetings with me. I guess Outlook only uses your main calendar for that.

Hiding the whole calendar from my phone isn't really an option; I still need to see the other events on my phone, such as when I have to be in meetings.

Basically, my question is: How may I hide select events on my Outlook Calendar from my Android Calendar?

Comment: Do you use a different Gmail for personal and work?  Why not just tell your Android phone to not show your work schedule?  Many of the Android calendar apps let you add more than one account and filter items out *by* account.

Comment: Yes, I do use a different Gmail for personal items, such as classes, group meetings, etc. However, my work calendar does have events in it that I would like to also see on my calendar, such as meetings with my team, unit meetings, etc. I would like to be able to view events from both my personal and work calendars together, excluding the "Out Of Office" recurring events.

Comment: What device and version of the OS? Are you using the stock calendar app?

Comment: Device: Motorola Atrix 4G. OS: Android 2.3.6. Yes, I am using the stock calendar app, I also downloaded and tried Business Calendar, and Jorte. But neither of them seemed to have the feature to hide select events.

Comment: I'm interested in a solution because I have the same issue.   I ended up not syncing my work, outlook calendar to my phone and just sync them up once a week.  Far from optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Propably this could give you a hint:

we have 3 accounts:

1. company@gmail.com
2. buddy1@gmail.com
3. buddy2@gmail.com

buddy1 and buddy2 added company@gmail.com's calendar as an external calendar (granted by company@gmail.com)

- buddy1 adds an event and sets it as "Private" & "Available" --> company & buddy2 see nothing!
- buddy1 adds an event and sets it as "Private" & "Busy" --> company & buddy2 see the appointment but can't read it's title or content, buddy1 of course can see his own appointment!

Comment: That looks like it might work. Maybe I could write a program to connect to my work email, download the calendar, and add all of the events to a calendar. Then, any of the events I don't want to see, I could post them as "Private" (or, maybe simply not even put them on the new calendar). That should like it would work, maybe as an app if I am able to access Google Calendar API from the phone, otherwise i may make it a daily running program on my computer. Any recommendations for this approach?

Answer (score -3):

You can go inside the Google calendar , either through a PC or a Mobile and click 'Display Calendars' above settings, and then choose which one(s) to show. If it is unchecked, it means you are going to hide the specific calendar.

Comment: Hiding an entire calendar is not the goal (and, besides, it has been suggested). The goal is to be able to hide individual events.

Comment: I mean to hide all events in a specific calender set you don't want to see not the whole calender. Your google calender itself can have many calender sets such as birthdays of your friends, working schedule and so on .

Comment: Yes. I know. That is not what the question asker is looking for.